# Find the index of the row in data frame that contains the string as value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have 2 data frames df and df1 from where I am comparing the values. What is exactly expected of the code is:

1) It iterates through data-frame df and when it meets certain
    conditions, it saves value in 10th column in variable 'value'. 
   2) it calls the function `GDN_func` and then in that data-frame df1,
    it iterates over column 'B' i.e. second column and compares its
    'items' to the value and if matched returns the `row_index`.

I have converted both the excel sheets into data-frames.
`row_index=df.index.get_loc(item)` will not give the results because the variable is stored as a String.

The code here is just a part.

I attached a snippet of my 2 data-frames and the code.

```
def GDN_func():
#defining GDN_func
    for item in (df1.iloc[:, 1]):
        if(item==value):
            p=df1[1].values.tolist().index(item)
            print(p) # This is not working

for row in range(0, mr-1):
    if((df.loc[row]['ATC']=='All') &
       (df.loc[row]['Data_Grain']=='Leadership Capability')):
        value=df.loc[row][10]
        GDN_func()
    else:
        print("These are different rows")
```

Comment: Can you provide a data sample? It's still a bit unclear to me how it looks like. Secondly, do you want to really obtain the index or the actual value from  df1? I don't see, what you're trying to do with the index.